# Are soft copies of ID proof acceptable for domestic air travel in India?

Tags: air-travel, paperwork, india

My daughter and I have to travel from Mysore to Hyderabad.  I don't have hard copies of our ID proofs with me, would it be fine to show soft copies of the ID proofs?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is valid ID for domestic flights in India?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/26319/what-is-valid-id-for-domestic-flights-in-india)

Comment: @mlc That answer doesn't specify whether copies are acceptable.

Comment: Looks like electronic version of Aadhar may be acceptable: https://www.ndtv.com/business/maadhaar-now-valid-for-entering-airports-how-to-download-use-aadhaar-app-1769601

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I have forgotten my ID proof and I'm doing an Indian domestic flight. Can I still fly?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/57142/i-have-forgotten-my-id-proof-and-im-doing-an-indian-domestic-flight-can-i-stil) (See the answer on e-Aadhar).

Comment: I have no experience of Indian travel but I'm willing to bet that neither soft nor hard copies of physical documents are acceptable. They are too easily forged. Electronic ID would be a different matter.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can travel with the soft copies as ids. According to a circular issued by aviation security agency BCAS. Mobile Aadhaar, or Aadhaar card in digital form using mobile app mAadhaar, can now be used as an identity proof to enter airports.

Comment: Note, this is the Aadhaar card, and its app. Not just any copy of any ID.